# Mumbling coworker

Tags: colleagues, conflict

I have a coworker who constantly mumbles under his breath impolite things about me or other coworkers. I find it very rude, because others can clearly hear him, although it's possible he is unaware that we do hear him.

His mumbling always consists of complaints about anything we do on the job,  to the point that it seems he has an issue with everything we do in our workplace. Yet, he never addresses his complains directly to anyone.

He also rolls his eyes or sighs whenever you assign him something he doesn’t want to do.

I don’t know how to get him to stop this behavior, and it's not just my problem - he disrupts the good feeling of our entire workplace.

I am reluctant to confront him directly because I don't want to cause personal enmity between us. What should I do?

Comment: And when you confront them about it they said...,?

Comment: Just mumble back.  “This guy is mumbling again what is his problem can’t he see how unprofessional it is” OK THANKS JIM!

Comment: What does your manager say when you ask about this? And have you looked at answers to other coworker questions?

Comment: What is your business relation to this co-worker?  Are you his manager?

Comment: By the way, I'm not the one who downvoted/mumbled about your question, but I assume you're getting downvoted because clearly you know the solution to your problem, you just haven't implemented it yet: "maybe I should say something directly to him because he just really bring the mood down."

Comment: _"You know we can hear that, right?"_

Comment: I’m confused as to why @Vector added *I don't want to cause personal enmity between us*. Obviously there already is a lot of personal animus if he is mumbling rude things about all of his coworkers within earshot.

Comment: @ColleenV _I try to be kind but honestly_   in the original.

Comment: @ColleenV _Obviously there already is a lot of personal animus_ No indication in the question that there is any personal animus **yet**. There may be undercurrents, but no mention of open hostilities. I believe that is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Vector If I have to refer to the edit history to understand why something changed meaning, the edits went too far. Do you have some personal knowledge of this situation or are you talking with the author?

Comment: @ColleenV - no change of meaning IMO. That is how I translate "I try to be kind..." - _I want to be nice - avoid confrontation which may be perceived as hostile_

Comment: Does he mumble anything about a stapler or setting the building on fire?

Comment: Ask your manager how to approach this.  There may be things you do not know.

Answer (score 8):

#### When people are rude to you, tell them to stop being rude.

"It's not okay to complain about me just because it's barely audible.  I need you to stop.  Are your eyes hurting, or are you rolling them to be rude? You know I can see you, right?"

When people are rude to you after you told them to stop, you take it to management.

When management lets people be rude to you, you find a place to work where people aren't jerks.

Comment: _When management lets people be rude to you, you find a place to work where people aren't jerks_ Often easier said than done. Not everyone can afford to play hard-ball.